# SSRS - Limit records by group

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which displays the records grouped by column "branch". Now i would like to limit my records to displays only 7 records per page. Break to display if the group is different. How do i do this?

Here is how i want my record to display.

Page 1:

Branch1

ID

1
2
3
4
5
6
7

Page 2:

Branch1

ID

8
9
10

Page 3:

Branch2

ID

11
12
13
14
15
16
17

Answer (score 1):

You could create a group based off an expression that divides the row number by 7 and adds 1, then set the page break property on the group. The expression for the group would be like:

```
=(Fields!RowNumber.Value  / 7) + 1
```

Comment: Hi, I don't have RowNumber as a field in my dataset. Is this something like =CEILING(RowNumber(Nothing)/7)?

Comment: It probably makes more sense to generate a row number in your dataset so that you can order the records appropriately.

Comment: I was able to address it by using row number (by partition helped me to acheive my requirement) logic in my stored procedure and then grouped it by rownumber. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. So this question is marked as answered?